# can I have library items my app plays show up as recently played in the Music app?

Tags: ios, swift, apple-musickit

My iOS app plays music from the user's library via `MPMusicPlayerController.applicationMusicPlayer`. It can either be from Apple Music or manually synced music files.

Is there a way to have that music show up as recently played in the Music app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out yes, it happens naturally if you launch playback of an album, as in querying the album by a MPMediaEntityPersistentID and giving the resulting MPMediaItemCollection as a queue to the player.

What I was doing though is creating a custom song queue for playback, usually from a given album, and then I'd expect the Music app to show that album as recently played. But the Music app won't pick it up that way.